# Flask will execute code in __init__.py but can't get it to run in app.py

Tags: python, flask

If I understand the documentation correctly, in Python3 Flask `___init___.py` is used for importing classes and can be completely empty.

I am trying to use app.py to hold my code, but I don't know how to get Flask to execute app.py. Code I put in `__init__.py` will execute, but I don't think I should do it that way. I have seen some posts where doing this could cause code to execute when it was just importing.

How do I get Flask to hit my app.py instead of `__init__.py`?

Here is my wsgi config file

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'something secret'
```

Comment: How are you starting Flask? Usually you'd do `export FLASK_APP=app.py` and `flask run` to start flask with the app being launched from `app.py`. If you're using `mod_wsgi` (as it seems like from your example), I'm guessing the `sys.path.insert` is wrong; you probably want that to be one level higher up, so that `FlaskApp` resolves _into_ the directory named `FlaskApp` and not as `/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp`.

Answer (score 0):

In my `wsgi.py` I just import the app (from app.py) and run it. I do have an older setup though but the approach should still apply.

```
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

and my `app.py` has the global Flask app variable along with all the other setup and Flask code (logging, routes, etc.)

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the `FLASK_APP` environment variable to your app.py file?

```
$ export FLASK_APP=app
$ flask run
```

See: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#application-discovery